# Word embedding microservices in the cloud

Tags: machine-learning-model, word-embeddings, aws

I would like to build nlp classifiers for various tasks such as sentiment analysis, topic modeling, name entity recognition etc. . I realized that most of them only involve simple logistic regression or  as small recurrent neural network taking embedded words as an input. **At the moment, I store a dictionary of the word embedding for each of my machine learning classifiers but I would like to replace it by a a micro-service which would be used by each of my machine learning model to retrieve the embedding of words**. I looked on the internet and could not find any sources which already implement thi (on AWS for example).

So I have two questions:

- Does it seems like a good idea to architect a large "farm" of nlp models
- Has any of you come across an open source solution which implement such word embedding microservice on the cloud.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I have very little knowledge about the technical side, but wouldn't this require a massive amount of bandwidth? I remember a time where everybody was proposing their NLP tasks as web services, but it turned out that transferring big corpora over the network was not as efficient as downloading the software and running it locally.